# Question about Hilbert transform of a cosine signal

Tags: hilbert-transform, amplitude-modulation

In the paper entitled "[On instantaneous frequency](https://doi.org/10.1142/S1793536909000096)", it is claimed that the Hilbert transform of a signal in the form of $A(t)cos(\phi(t))$ would result in $A(t)sin(\phi(t))$, where $A(t)$ is instantaneous amplitude and $\phi(t)$ is the phase function. 
As an example, consider the following:
$$t = [0, 20],\;\textrm{time interval in seconds, sampled each 0.01 sec}$$
$$A(t) = e^{-0.1(t - 10)^2},\;\textrm{instantaneous  amplitude}$$
$$\omega = [0.1,\ 0.5,\ 1.0,\ 1.5],\;\textrm{angular  frequency  in rad/sec}$$
$$f(t) = A(t)\cos(\omega t)$$
$$g(t) = A(t)\sin(\omega t)$$
$$h(t) = \frac{1}{\pi}P\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\frac{f(\tau)}{t - \tau}dt,\;\textrm{Hilbert  transform  of } f(t)\textrm{,  where } P  \textrm{ is the   Cauchy  principal  value}$$
It is expected that $g(t)$ and $h(t)$ be the same according to the fact claimed in mentioned paper. I used function "hilbert" of MATLAB to compute Hilbert transform of $f(t)$ for aforementioned $\omega$ values. Results show that for $\omega$ close to zero, $g(t)$ and $h(t)$ are different and as $\omega$ gets higher, the difference decreases. I was wondering if I am making a mistake or something is wrong with function "hilbert" of MATLAB? 
The following figure shows the results:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure that you understand the conditions under which

$$\mathcal{H}\big\{A(t)\cos(\omega_0 t)\big\}=A(t)\mathcal{H}\big\{\cos(\omega_0 t)\big\}=A(t)\sin(\omega_0t)\tag{1}$$

holds. Eq. $(1)$ holds if $A(t)$ is a low-pass signal with a cut-off frequency smaller than $\omega_0$. This implies that $A(t)\cos(\omega_0t)$ is a band-pass signal with no energy at DC. Eq. $(1)$ is a special case of [Bedrosian's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert_transform#Bedrosian's_theorem).

In your example, $A(t)$ is not band-limited, and, consequently, $(1)$ doesn't hold. However, if you increase the modulation frequency $\omega_0$, the overlap of the spectra of $A(t)$ and of the carrier becomes smaller, because $A(t)$ does have a low pass character. So for large $\omega_0$, Eq. $(1)$ is approximately satisfied, which is exactly what you see in your plots.

Also take a look at [this related answer](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/a/66866/4298).

Answer (score 1):

The claim is generally false. This is studied in details in a 1997 paper by B. Picinbono: [On instantaneous amplitude and phase of signals](https://doi.org/10.1109/78.558469)

> Let $m(t)$ be a positive function corresponding to the information o
>   be transmitted. By multiplying the carrier frequency signal
>   $cos(\omega_0 t)$ by $m(t)$, we obtain the signal $x(t) = m(t)
> > cos(\omega_0 t)$  and it is commonly admitted that is $m(t)$ the
>   instantaneous amplitude of the signal $x(t)$. This appears in many
>   textbooks
>
> This leads to the conclusion that the definitions given previously,
>   even if they are widely used, are incoherent because they do not
>   associate with a given real signal a well-defined pair of functions
>   that are the instantaneous amplitude and phase of $x(t)$.

The basis of the the claim resides in the Bedrosian theorem, that asserts that, **in some conditions**, the Hilbert transform $\mathcal{H}$ can apply separately on a product

$$\mathcal{H}[x_1(t)x_2(t)] = x_1(t)\mathcal{H}[x_2(t)]$$

The classical condition is of "distinct frequency supports": that $x_1(t)$ is strictly band-limited above $B$ (ie zero-spectrum for $\nu> B$, and  $x_2(t)$ is strictly band-limited below $B$ (ie zero-spectrum for $\nu< B$). This condition does not hold with the Gaussian  function, since it is not band-limited. However, when you increase $\omega$, the overlap between the Gaussian and the carrier sine has less energy, and the claim becomes "less false" in simulations.

Further, if $a(t)$ and $cos[φ(t)]$ have distinct supports (as above), one has:
$$\mathcal{H}({a(t) \cos[\phi(t)]}) = a(t)\mathcal{H}({\cos[\phi(t)]})$$
but one cannot say that:

$$\mathcal{H}({\cos[\phi(t)]}) = \sin[\phi(t)]\;\textrm{ (false in general)}$$