# Proof of Bedrosian's theorem

Tags: fourier-transform, hilbert-transform, proof

I was looking for a straightforward proof for Bedrosian's theorem which says **the Hilbert transform of the baseband signal  times the passband signal is the original baseband signal times the Hilbert transform of the passband signal** in which by assuming $x(t)$ is a passband signal and and $m(t)$ is a baseband signal, then we have :
$$c(t)=\widehat{x(t)m(t)}=\widehat {x(t)}m(t)$$
Now for the sake of proof since we know Fourier transform of Hilbert  equals to  :
$$\hat X(f)=-j\operatorname{sgn}(f)X(f)$$
Then we say :
$$\hat c(f)=-j\operatorname{sgn}(f) [x(f) \star m(f)]$$
Now can we say( because $x(t)$ is a passband signal) $X(f)$ is only in positive f part and $\operatorname{sgn}(f)$ value is constant and bring it in? and then we have:
$$[-j\operatorname{sgn}(f)x(f)] \star m(f)=\widehat {x(f)}\star m(f)$$
And so we can say

$$\hat c(f)=\widehat {x(f)}\star m(f)$$
$$\hat c(t)=\widehat{x(t)m(t)}=\widehat {x(t)}m(t)$$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One easy way to see the validity of the theorem is to consider the corresponding analytic signals. Let a signal $s(t)$ be defined by

$$s(t)=m(t)c(t)\tag{1}$$

where $m(t)$ is a low pass (message) signal, and $c(t)$ is a bandpass (carrier) signal. Note that we don't need to assume that $c(t)$ is sinusoidal. Let $\hat{s}(t)$ denote the Hilbert transform of $s(t)$, and $\hat{c}(t)$ is the Hilbert transform of $c(t)$.

The equality claimed by Bedrosian's theorem

$$\hat{s}(t)=m(t)\hat{c}(t)\tag{2}$$

is equivalent to

$$s_a(t)=m(t)c_a(t)\tag{3}$$

where $s_a(t)$ and $c_a(t)$ denote the analytic signals corresponding to $s(t)$ and $c(t)$, respectively. Analytic signals are complex-valued signals having only positive frequency components. The analytic signal is given by the original signal plus its Hilbert transform as the imaginary part:

$$s_a(t)=s(t)+j\hat{s}(t)\tag{4}$$

In the frequency domain, the signal $m(t)c_a(t)$ is centered at the (positive) center frequency of the bandpass signal $c(t)$. Its bandwidth equals the bandwidth of $c(t)$ plus twice the bandwidth of the lowpass signal $m(t)$. It has only positive frequency components if the spectra of $m(t)$ and $c(t)$ do not overlap. In that case it equals the analytic signal $s_a(t)$, as claimed in Eq. $(3)$. Otherwise, $m(t)c_a(t)$ has also negative frequency components and $(3)$ is not satisfied.

Note that $(2)$ and $(3)$ are also valid if $c(t)$ is a highpass signal, as long as the spectra of $m(t)$ and $c(t)$ don't overlap.

Also take a look at [this related answer](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/a/66866/4298) and the figure therein.

Comment: Thanks , so i suppose my proof was wrong , right ?

Comment: @Elias: Your argument wasn't very clear to me.

Comment: @MattL. Did you mean $s(t)$ instead of $x(t)$ in your second paragraph?

Comment: @DanBoschen: Yes, I did. Corrected, thx.